# ggplot and lapply /mapply for nested list and data frames

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, mapply

Edit:

I did find a way to do what I need, but now I'm having trouble getting a title to appear for each of the plots that are created so I know which site I am looking at:

```
lapply(seq(gl), function(i){
    lapply(seq(gl[[i]]), function(j){
        ggplot() +
            geom_point(data = gl[[i]][[j]], aes(x = `UTC_date.1`, y = `actSWE_mm`, color = `swe_Res_mm`))+
            geom_segment(data = gl[[i]][[j]], aes(x = `UTC_date.1`, y = `actSWE_mm`, xend = `UTC_date.1`, yend = `swe_mm`), alpha=.2)+
            scale_color_steps2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
            guides(color = FALSE) + geom_point(data = gl[[i]][[j]], aes(x = `UTC_date.1`, y = `swe_mm`), shape = 1) + 
            facet_wrap(vars(year), scales="free_x") +  theme_bw() 
    })})
```

I tried adding:

theme(plot.title = paste(names(gl)[i], names(gl[[i]])[j], sep = "_"))

but that does not seem to work.

---

Original:

I have a list of 12 dataframes representing each month. Within each data frame are timeseries measurements of several different sites. Below is a table example (not actual data) of the data for January (monthSplit is the list - monthSplit$January):

```
 site_id   UTC_date.1    swe_mm    actSWE_mm  swe_Res_mm  Month        Year
     <int>   <date>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <chr>        <num>
     1003 2005-01-01 2   54.2        0.241      53.059    "January"     2005
     1003 2005-01-02 2   54.2        0.241      53.059    "January"     2005
     958  2005-01-01 2   154.2       0.241      153.059   "January"     2005
     946  2005-01-01 2   154.2       152.25     1.95      "January"     2005
     946  2005-01-02 2   500.2       550.241    50.059    "January"     2005
```

I'm having two problems when trying to perform ggplot over a list of dataframes that need to be further subset by the unique sites.

I tried to create a ggplot function and use mapply:

```
plot_fun = function(d) {
  ggplot(d, aes(x = `UTC_date.1`, y = `actSWE_mm`)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = `UTC_date.1`, yend = `swe_mm`), alpha=.2) + geom_point(aes(color = `swe_Res_mm`))  +
    scale_color_steps2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") +
    guides(color = FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y = `swe_mm`), shape = 1) + 
    facet_wrap(vars(year), scales="free_x") +  theme_bw() 
}
```

```
pltlist = mapply(plot_fun, d = monthSplit, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

This yielded plot in the right format and everything, however it was not split by site_id. So it created a plot that contained several plots with the month's plot values each year. EG: September plot yielded 13 plots in one window representing each year from 2003-2015 for the month of September. The problem is, all the sites were lumped in there.

When looking at the actual data (as is the case with the above plot function), nothing meaningful is gained from the plots because the range of data varies so broadly in the y-axis.

I was wondering how I would go about splitting the list of plots further by site_id so that only one site appears in each plot for comparison.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example which illustrates the issues you are having. You probably do not need to include the mass of data you have in your actual case to get to the nub of the problem; have a look at [mre] or https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5

Comment: I edited to show the problem, or gap in knowledge on my part rather.

Answer (score 0):

Add group = site_id if you want to have one color point and line per site_id, e.g.

`plot_fun = function(d) { ggplot(d, aes(x = UTC_date.1, y = actSWE_mm, group = site_id)) + geom_segment(aes(xend = UTC_date.1, yend = swe_mm), alpha=.2) + geom_point(aes(color = swe_Res_mm))  + scale_color_steps2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red") + guides(color = FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y = swe_mm), shape = 1) + facet_wrap(vars(year), scales="free_x") +  theme_bw() }`

(Note I had to delete all your '`' characters as that is the code character).
Not this proposal gives not more plots, but more lines per plot.

If you want to have one plots per site_id, you might split your datasets by that variable, or include it in the facet_wrap:
`facet_wrap(facets = ~ year + site_id, scales="free_x")`

And if the scales are very different per site, I use log scales. However, zeros and negative values cannot be graphed then, that is a drawback.

Comment: That definitely helped to at least distinguish between the sites on the same plot. Thanks! This works well with standardized residuals. 
 
Now I just need to figure out how to split the plots. If I use split again it feels messy because its already a set of data frames within a list which would then be split again?

Comment: you can split, and unlist the list to get a 1 level list instead of a 2 level list. Or use flatten from purrr: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164715/how-to-remove-a-level-of-lists-from-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: by the way is it not easier to  would put all data in one dataset if they all have the same format (using rbind) and then select the subsets for each plot? It allows other slicing to happen than the one you have used for the split.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'm not sure I understand how to call it after? If I use rbind, I get a matrix with a list under every month.

Comment: I meant rbind should be to stack them together into a data.frame with an extra column which identifies the data set.